# Portion of Hashed password seen as variable by MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpass

Using phpass to generate hashes, the following string is generated:

`$2a$08$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew//bCc7rxMuY1rtDApwA66/czIiurLi`

Then a standard query:

```
"INSERT INTO su_auth ( 
                      AuthAlias, AuthUsername, 
                      AuthPass, 
                      AuthSessionID, AuthIP, AuthUserAgent
                    )
                    VALUES ( 
                      'Me', 'Myself',         
                      '$2a$08$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew//bCc7rxMuY1rtDApwA66/czIiurLi', 
                       NULL, NULL, NULL
                    )"
```

A problem arises when the portion `$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew` is viewed as an empty variable and submitted as such (i.e. a null value). The stored string is therefore: `$2a$08//bCc7rxMuY1rtDApwA66/czIiurLi`. Placing a backslash before the `$` works, but is obviously not feasible.

Why does this happen within a quoted string? Why do the preceding `$`'s not trigger the same reaction? What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: [Use single quotes instead of double quotes for the query.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @PeeHaa I can do that, but I also want to know why it's happening to that portion specifically, and not the other `$`'s

Comment: [Variablenames in PHP don't start with a number.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: Oh. Simple as. OK! If you want, submit an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing what you are seeing is because you use a [double quoted string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for the query. In PHP single quoted string are interpreted by PHP. So what happens in your case is that PHP reads the query and sees a variable `$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew`.

This variable is never set obviously and as suck results in a notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew in...

And will result in `null` (again because the variable is never set).

To see how PHP reads the string see this [explain page](http://explain.so/?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2FPeeHaa%2Ff864b7e1ec1881f77d60%2Fraw%2Fexplain.php).

Now to answer your question why the other `$` are not being interpreted as variables. This has to do with the fact that PHP variables don't start with a number. So PHP knows `$2` can never be a variable.

Valid variable names in PHP [look like](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
```

<sub>There is a way to let a variable start with a number in PHP though: `${'2a'} = 'foo';`</sub>

So you have four choices to fix your code:

**Use single quotes**

```
'INSERT INTO su_auth ( 
     AuthAlias, AuthUsername, AuthPass, AuthSessionID, AuthIP, AuthUserAgent
 ) VALUES ( 
     \'Me\',
     \'Myself\',                                  
     \'$2a$08$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew//bCc7rxMuY1rtDApwA66/czIiurLi\', 
     NULL, NULL, NULL
 )'
```

**Concatenate**

```
"INSERT INTO su_auth ( 
     AuthAlias, AuthUsername, AuthPass, AuthSessionID, AuthIP, AuthUserAgent
 ) VALUES ( 
     'Me',
     'Myself',                                  
     '". '$2a$08$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew//bCc7rxMuY1rtDApwA66/czIiurLi' . "', 
     NULL, NULL, NULL
 )"
```

[**sprintf**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
echo sprintf("INSERT INTO su_auth (AuthAlias, AuthUsername, AuthPass, AuthSessionID, AuthIP, AuthUserAgent) VALUES ('Me', 'Myself', '%s', null, null, null)", '$2a$08$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew//bCc7rxMuY1rtDApwA66/czIiurLi');
```

**WHY ARE YOU USING YOUR DATA DIRECTLY IN YOUR QUERY??? [Use prepared statements with bound parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO su_auth (AuthAlias, AuthUsername, AuthPass, AuthSessionID, AuthIP, AuthUserAgent) VALUES (:AuthAlias, :AuthUsername, :AuthPass, :AuthSessionID, :AuthIP, :AuthUserAgent)');
$stmt->execute([
    'AuthAlias'     => 'Me',
    'AuthUsername'  => 'Myself',
    'AuthPass'      => '$2a$08$KHiiru4yzYh141GUh2xIMew//bCc7rxMuY1rtDApwA66/czIiurLi',
    'AuthSessionID' => null,
    'AuthIP'        => null,
    'AuthUserAgent' => null,
]);
```

Option four would be preferred.